# Delete a child record from the parent collection

Tags: nhibernate, parent-child

I'm developing a sample application so that I can learn the ins and outs of NHibernate. I am struggling with a delete issue. I wish to be able to delete a child record by removing it from its parent’s collection and then saving the parent. I have setup a bidirectional one-to-many relationship and inserting/updating is working great.

Here are my mappings

Basket:

`<bag name="Items" inverse="true" cascade="all">
     <key column="BasketId" />
      <one-to-many class="BasketItem" />
    </bag>`

BasketItem:

`<many-to-one not-null="true" name="Basket" column="BasketId" />`

I would like to call `basket.RemoveBasketItem(BasketItem item)` then `Session.SaveUpdate(basket)` so that the basket item will be deleted. Is this possible?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Change `cascade="all"` into `cascade="all-delete-orphan"`.

`cascade="all"` will only delete your child records if the parent gets deleted.

Comment: When my RemoveBasketItem looks like this: this.basketItems.Remove(itemToRemove); I get this error: A collection with cascade="all-delete-orphan" was no longer referenced by the owning entity instance: Basket.Items

Comment: Sounds like you somehow overwrote the `IList` reference holding your basket items. You can only put your own implementation of `IList` in there when the list reference is null - if you load a basket from the DB, NH will put its own `PersistentBag` as the `IList` implementation - and you must leave this reference alone for cascade to work properly.

Comment: I got it to work! Thanks for your help :-) I was having problems because my basket.Items property was newing up a read-only List. Now I am simply returning the private instance of my items.

Comment: This change means my basket items could be modified by client code :-( basket.Items.Add(). I will need to look into this a bit more.

Comment: I usually make AddItem/RemoveItem methods, and then have my property return only an IEnumerable<Item> - this way, the consuming code must new up their own List or whatever they want to do, and they never accidentally modify the persistent list.

Comment: This answer has nothing with the question.

Answer (score 2):

I have same scenario and ive used cascade="all-delete-orphan" in bagList but when i delete a single child item in a collection it deletes the parent object as well.

Comment: Make sure your child object has cascade="none"

Comment: Thanks for the comment .... this is the missing link in most of the entries online!!!

Comment: +1 million, helped me out where most online resources fail to mention, as Jonathan said. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem as initforthemoney due to returning a new list as ReadOnly from my collection getter. I found I could continue to use the ReadOnly list by changing the property access strategy of the collection from `nosetter` to `field`.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a problem where my children elements where returning an Ordered enumerable.

```
private readonly IList<Child> children;

public virtual IEnumerable<Child> Children { get { return children.OrderBy(c => c.Position); } }

public virtual void DeleteChild(Child item)
{
    children.Remove(item);
}
```

I moved the ordering to my mapping and returned the children as it is for the IEnumerable. This worked for me!